# Solve matrix DAE system in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, symbolic-math, ode, differential-equations

The equations can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251929/what-is-the-index-of-a-given-dae-system-of-equations). As you can see it is set of 8 scalar equations closed to 3 matrix ones. In order to let Matlab know that equations are matrix - wise, I declare variable time dependent vector functions as:

```
syms t p1(t) p2(t) p3(t)
p(t) = symfun([p1(t);p2(t);p3(t)], t);
p = formula(p(t));  % allows indexing for vector p
% same goes for w(t) and m(t)...
```

Known matrices are declared as follows:

```
A = sym('A%d%d',[3 3]);
Fq = sym('Fq%d%d',[2 3]);
Im = diag(sym('Im%d%d',[1 3]));
```

The system is now ready to be modeled according to [guide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/set-up-your-dae-problem.html):

```
eqs = [diff(p) == A*w + Fq'*m,...
       diff(w) == -Im*p,...
       Fq*w == 0];
vars = [p; w; m];
```

At this point, when I try to reduce index (since it equals 2), I receive following error:

```
[DAEs,DAEvars] = reduceDAEIndex(eqs,vars);

Error using sym/reduceDAEIndex (line 95)
Expecting as many equations as variables.
```

---

The error would not arise if we had declared all variables as scalars:

```
syms A Im Fq real p(t) w(t) m(t)
```

Quoting `symfun` [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html) (tips section):

> Symbolic functions are always scalars, therefore, you cannot index into a function.

However it is hard for me to believe that it's not possible to solve these equations matrix - wise. Obviously, one can expand it to 8 scalar equations, but the multi body system concerned here is very simple and the aim is to be able to solve complex ones - hence the question: is it possible to solve matrix DAE in Matlab, and if so - what has to be fixed in order for this to work?

---

Ps. I have another issue with Matlab DAE solver: input variables (known coefficient functions) for my model are time variant. As far as [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/convert-dae-systems-to-matlab-function-handles.html) is concerned, they are constant in all domain, however for my problem they change in time. This problem has been brought out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348813/how-to-solve-dae-with-a-varying-input-a-time-dependent-input-function-in-matla). I would be grateful if you referred to it, should you have any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to find correct syntax for this problem. I made a mistake of treating matrix variables (such as `A`, `Fq`) as a single entity. Below I present code that utilizes matrix approach and solves this particular DAE:

```
% Define symbolic variables.
q = sym('q%d',[3 1]);        % state variables
a = sym('a'); k = sym('k');  % constant parameters
t = sym('t','real');         % independent variable

% Define system variables and group them in vectors:
p1(t) = sym('p1(t)'); p2(t) = sym('p2(t)'); p3(t) = sym('p3(t)');
w1(t) = sym('w1(t)'); w2(t) = sym('w2(t)'); w3(t) = sym('w3(t)');
m1(t) = sym('m1(t)'); m2(t) = sym('m2(t)');
pvect = [p1(t); p2(t); p3(t)];
wvect = [w1(t); w2(t); w3(t)];
mvect = [m1(t); m2(t)];

% Define matrices:
mass = diag(sym('ms%d',[1 3]));
Fq = [0 -1 a;
      0  0 1];
A = [1  0  0;
     0  1  a;
     0  a -q(1)*a] * k;

% Define sets of equations and aggregate them into one set: 
set1 = diff(pvect,t) == A*wvect + Fq'*mvect;
set2 = mass*diff(wvect,t) == -pvect;
set3 = Fq*wvect == 0;
eqs = [set1; set2; set3];
% Close all system variables in one vector:
vars = [pvect; wvect; mvect];

% Reduce index of the system and remove redundnat equations:
[DAEs,DAEvars] = reduceDAEIndex(eqs,vars);
[DAEs,DAEvars] = reduceRedundancies(DAEs,DAEvars);
[M,F] = massMatrixForm(DAEs,DAEvars);
```

We receive very simple `2x2` ODE for two variables `p1(t)` and `w1(t)`. Keep in mind that after reducing redundancies we got rid of all elements from state vector `q`. This means that all left variables (`k` and `mass(1,1)`) are not time dependent. If there had been time dependency of some variables within the system, the case would have been much harder to solve.

```
% Replace symbolic variables with numeric ones:
M = odeFunction(M, DAEvars,mass(1,1));
F = odeFunction(F, DAEvars, k);
k = 2000; numericMass = 4;
F = @(t, Y) F(t, Y, k);
M = @(t, Y) M(t, Y, numericMass);

% set the solver:
opt = odeset('Mass', M); % Mass matrix of the system
TIME = [1; 0];           % Time boundaries of the simulation (backwards in time)
y0 = [1 0]';             % Initial conditions for left variables p1(t) and w1(t)

% Call the solver
[T, solution] = ode15s(F, TIME, y0, opt);
% Plot results
plot(T,solution(:,1),T,solution(:,2))
```